# Swipe to delete without jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Im not able to find **"swipe to delete"** function build without jquery or jquery mobile...There is not any pure javascript version ? really ?

I found only this build with jquery >

```
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/examples/swipe/swipe-list.html#demo-page

https://github.com/ksloan/jquery-mobile-swipe-list

http://codepen.io/Palestinian/pen/xBDHi/
```

nothing better...
I will be very grateful for any opinion and help!
Thanks

Comment: Of course there is the option to do it without jQuery. jQuery is just a library of JS functions whose functionality could all be implemented by themselves. But as far as the workload is concerned I would not do this. Why are you reluctant to use jQuery?

Comment: Because I'm building webapp without jquery and I don't wanna add here jQuery only because this swipe function. So I already found it !!! look at it ! https://github.com/pornel/slip

Comment: Looks like a good solution. You should post that as a self answer and accept it. It might be useful for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guys I finally found the solution! Please take a look it is only 16kb minified insted 96KB (jQuery 1.11.2) + jquery swipe plugin

https://pornel.net/slip/